# Create a preloader page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a preloader page for my website but i don't know how to setup it in javascript, i've create all the css but i need help to create the transiction for switch from the loader to the page.

```css
.caricamento {
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  float: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 48%;
}

#cerchiodentro,#loading #cherchiodentro
{
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 margin:20px 0 0 20px;
 
 width:40px;
 height:40px;
 border-top:7px solid #f22121;
 border-bottom:7px solid #f22121;
 border-left:7px solid transparent;
 border-right:7px solid transparent;
 
 border-radius:40px;
 -moz-border-radius:40px;
 -webkit-border-radius:40px;
 -ms-border-radius:40px;
 -o-border-radius:40px;
 
 box-shadow:0 0 20px #f22121;
 -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px #f22121;
 -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px #f22121;
 -ms-box-shadow:0 0 20px #f22121;
 -o-box-shadow:0 0 20px #f22121;
 
 -webkit-animation: ccwSpin .555s linear .2s infinite;
 -moz-animation: ccwSpin .555s linear .2s infinite;
 -o-animation: ccwSpin .555s linear .2s infinite;
 -ms-animation: ccwSpin .555s linear .2s infinite;
 animation: ccwSpin .555s linear .2s infinite;
}

#loading #cerchiofuori
{
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 margin:0 auto;

 width:80px;
 height:80px;
 border-top:7px solid #f22121;
 border-bottom:7px solid transparent;
 border-left:7px solid transparent;
 border-right:7px solid 06F;
 
 border-radius:80px;
 -moz-border-radius:80px;
 -webkit-border-radius:80px;
 -ms-border-radius:80px;
 -o-border-radius:80px;
 
 -webkit-animation: cwSpin 1s linear .2s infinite;
 -moz-animation: cwSpin .666s linear .2s infinite;
 -o-animation: cwSpin .666s linear .2s infinite;
 -ms-animation: cwSpin .666s linear .2s infinite;
 animation: cwSpin .666s linear .2s infinite;
}

#loading #cerchiodentro
{
 
 border-top:7px solid transparent;
 border-bottom:7px solid #f22121;
 border-left:7px solid #f22121;
 border-right:7px solid transparent;
 
 box-shadow:none;
 -moz-box-shadow:none;
 -ms-box-shadow:none;
 -o-box-shadow:none;
 -webkit-box-shadow:none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes cwSpin
{
 0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes cwSpin
{
 0%{-moz-transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{-moz-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
@-ms-keyframes cwSpin
{
 0%{-ms-transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{-ms-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes cwSpin
{
 0%{-o-transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{-o-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes cwSpin
{
 0%{transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{transform:rotate(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes ccwSpin
{
 0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes ccwSpin
{
 0%{-moz-transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{-moz-transform:rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-ms-keyframes ccwSpin
{
 0%{-ms-transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{-ms-transform:rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes ccwSpin
{
 0%{-o-transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{-o-transform:rotate(-360deg); }
}
@keyframes ccwSpin
{
 0%{transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{transform:rotate(-360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="caricamento">
  <span id="loading">
        <span id="cerchiofuori"></span>
        <span id="cerchiodentro"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

For the javascript i found this but i don't know how to adapt this to my page, some one can help me please?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').addClass('loaded');
        $('h1').css('color','#222222');
    }, 3000);

});
```

^^^ This code is wrong but this is what i found

Thanks for all the answer

Comment: What do you mean by "preloader"?

Comment: i give you a link: https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/css3-preloader-transition/
the animation when you open the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `document.onreadystatechange` event. When it is triggered just check the status, when it is `complete` the page is loaded, follow the code:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (document.readyState == "loading") {    
      //action while loading
   }else if(document.readyState == "complete") {
      //action when page is loaded
      //this hide the .caraicamento after page is loaded and with a delay of 1-second  
      $('.caricamento').delay(1000).hide('slow');
   }
}
```

This is **the best way to know if the page has been loaded**, but can be used along with a delay so the animation has a minimum time on the screen!

Answer (score 3):

you can use `$('.caricamento').hide()` to hide the loader in `setTimeout()` after 3 seconds.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

setTimeout(function(){
    $('.caricamento').hide();
}, 3000);

});
```

```css
.caricamento {
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  float: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 48%;
}

#cerchiodentro,#loading #cherchiodentro
{
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 margin:20px 0 0 20px;
 
 width:40px;
 height:40px;
 border-top:7px solid #f22121;
 border-bottom:7px solid #f22121;
 border-left:7px solid transparent;
 border-right:7px solid transparent;
 
 border-radius:40px;
 -moz-border-radius:40px;
 -webkit-border-radius:40px;
 -ms-border-radius:40px;
 -o-border-radius:40px;
 
 box-shadow:0 0 20px #f22121;
 -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px #f22121;
 -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px #f22121;
 -ms-box-shadow:0 0 20px #f22121;
 -o-box-shadow:0 0 20px #f22121;
 
 -webkit-animation: ccwSpin .555s linear .2s infinite;
 -moz-animation: ccwSpin .555s linear .2s infinite;
 -o-animation: ccwSpin .555s linear .2s infinite;
 -ms-animation: ccwSpin .555s linear .2s infinite;
 animation: ccwSpin .555s linear .2s infinite;
}

#loading #cerchiofuori
{
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 margin:0 auto;

 width:80px;
 height:80px;
 border-top:7px solid #f22121;
 border-bottom:7px solid transparent;
 border-left:7px solid transparent;
 border-right:7px solid 06F;
 
 border-radius:80px;
 -moz-border-radius:80px;
 -webkit-border-radius:80px;
 -ms-border-radius:80px;
 -o-border-radius:80px;
 
 -webkit-animation: cwSpin 1s linear .2s infinite;
 -moz-animation: cwSpin .666s linear .2s infinite;
 -o-animation: cwSpin .666s linear .2s infinite;
 -ms-animation: cwSpin .666s linear .2s infinite;
 animation: cwSpin .666s linear .2s infinite;
}

#loading #cerchiodentro
{
 
 border-top:7px solid transparent;
 border-bottom:7px solid #f22121;
 border-left:7px solid #f22121;
 border-right:7px solid transparent;
 
 box-shadow:none;
 -moz-box-shadow:none;
 -ms-box-shadow:none;
 -o-box-shadow:none;
 -webkit-box-shadow:none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes cwSpin
{
 0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes cwSpin
{
 0%{-moz-transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{-moz-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
@-ms-keyframes cwSpin
{
 0%{-ms-transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{-ms-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes cwSpin
{
 0%{-o-transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{-o-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes cwSpin
{
 0%{transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{transform:rotate(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes ccwSpin
{
 0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes ccwSpin
{
 0%{-moz-transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{-moz-transform:rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-ms-keyframes ccwSpin
{
 0%{-ms-transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{-ms-transform:rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes ccwSpin
{
 0%{-o-transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{-o-transform:rotate(-360deg); }
}
@keyframes ccwSpin
{
 0%{transform:rotate(0deg); }
 100%{transform:rotate(-360deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="caricamento">
  <span id="loading">
        <span id="cerchiofuori"></span>
        <span id="cerchiodentro"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Lafa you are welcome, consider accepting the answer if it helped. Cheers!

Comment: Yes you helped me but i need to wait 5 mins

Comment: i'm in a mistake because he gived me the perfect jquery. UP

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.delay()` and one of jQuery animation methods, for example, `.fadeOut()`. Note, `.loaded` is not defined at CSS.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".caricamento").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow")
})
```

```css
.caricamento {
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  float: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 48%;
}

#cerchiodentro,
#loading #cherchiodentro {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-top: 7px solid #f22121;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #f22121;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 40px;
  -moz-border-radius: 40px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  -ms-border-radius: 40px;
  -o-border-radius: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #f22121;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #f22121;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #f22121;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #f22121;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #f22121;
  -webkit-animation: ccwSpin .555s linear .2s infinite;
  -moz-animation: ccwSpin .555s linear .2s infinite;
  -o-animation: ccwSpin .555s linear .2s infinite;
  -ms-animation: ccwSpin .555s linear .2s infinite;
  animation: ccwSpin .555s linear .2s infinite;
}

#loading #cerchiofuori {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-top: 7px solid #f22121;
  border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid 06F;
  border-radius: 80px;
  -moz-border-radius: 80px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 80px;
  -ms-border-radius: 80px;
  -o-border-radius: 80px;
  -webkit-animation: cwSpin 1s linear .2s infinite;
  -moz-animation: cwSpin .666s linear .2s infinite;
  -o-animation: cwSpin .666s linear .2s infinite;
  -ms-animation: cwSpin .666s linear .2s infinite;
  animation: cwSpin .666s linear .2s infinite;
}

#loading #cerchiodentro {
  border-top: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #f22121;
  border-left: 7px solid #f22121;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes cwSpin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes cwSpin {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes cwSpin {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes cwSpin {
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes cwSpin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes ccwSpin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes ccwSpin {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes ccwSpin {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes ccwSpin {
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes ccwSpin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="caricamento">
  <span id="loading">
        <span id="cerchiofuori"></span>
  <span id="cerchiodentro"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```